# HTML5 mobile browser support

Tags: html, mobile

Trying to determine if any Android browsers (or other mobile platform browsers) support HTML5 drag and drop.

Is there an up-to-date online reference for HTML5 feature support within browsers?  Specifically mobile browsers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is what you want: http://caniuse.com/

Comment: if you just want to check HTML5 support, and only in iOS Safari and Android Browser, use this link: http://caniuse.com/#agents=ios_saf,android&eras=farpast,past,now&cats=HTML5

Answer (score 8):

MobileHTML5 http://mobilehtml5.org/ is an interesting reference where to check for html5 support on mobile devices

Answer (score 1):

This shows a lot of mobile related tables,maintaned by @ppk

http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/

This is specifically for touch events: http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableTouch.html