# Table of Mobile Devices support HTML5?

Tags: html, mobile

Does anyone know of a table that lists all devices currently supporting HTML5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 mobile browser support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100149/html5-mobile-browser-support)

Comment: It doesn't ask only about Android...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Web site: http://caniuse.com/

Answer (score 0):

I consider those better:

http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/ (maintained by @ppk )

http://mobilehtml5.org/ (maintained by @firt )