# HTML5 sessionStorage compatibility with mobile browser

Tags: html, compatibility, mobile-browser, session-storage

I want to know the compatibility of HTML5 or more specific sessionStorage in different mobile Browser. I want to know about below browsers:
1. iOS 3.2 onwards
2. Android 2.1 - 2.3
3. Windows phone 7 - 7.5
4. Blackberry 6.0 and 7.0

Thanks in advance,
Ratnesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google search leads to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6100149/1035945) on here already. One of the answers [links](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/) to a site with great information about html5 support in mobile browsers.